# What is meaning of "SOAP requires more bandwidth and resource than REST"?

Tags: rest, web-services, soap

What is meaning of "SOAP requires more bandwidth and resource than REST" and "REST requires less bandwidth and resource than SOAP". What is Bandwidth and Resource author is referring too?

Comment: Which book you reffer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST isn't a JSON based exchange of data but a technique to decouple clients from servers. The decoupling is achieved by utilizing well-defined operations of a transport protocol that form the common interface for the message exchange and by relying on well-defined, intermediary media types that describe the syntax and semantics of the data exchanged. There is though no indication that data exchanged via application that follow the REST model need less bandwith (send smaller payloads) than if exchanged via SOAP.

Why? A server that adheres to the REST principles will include plenty more options a client can use to take further actions which thus (may) bloat up the actual response and actually may require more bandwith than RPC messages exchanged via SOAP. A quote like the one from the author you are refering to, should be treated thus with special care. In addition to that, if a payload is trasfered in an XML representation, both appraoches have litteraly the same overhead on the actual exchanged syntax. Sure, SOAP may introduce the SOAP envelope, though this is mainly used to specify certain required capabilities like transaction support or the like.

The author is probably building his statement on what plenty of people consider REST but is actually RPC just via HTTP and JSON payload. Plenty of so called REST APIs are just JSON based Web APIs that more or less adhere to the HTTP operation semantics but dictate a client on how to use their services by sending proprietary JSON payload in `application/json` format to clients. As this media-type is pretty generic and also does not support clients in determining the semantics of the payload, a client can't really make sense of such a response format unless the knowledge is already coded into the client and thus tightly couples it to the API itself and may break if the server ever decides to return a slightly differen representation (due to updates or the like). Such representation are usually tailor made for the API and do not contain additional URIs or hints on further actions as the knowledge is already build into the client (similar to SOAP RPC).

I hope you can see that such a statement should be treated with care if you compare REST (in its true meaning) with SOAP message payload size. A server that provides clients with every option possible so it can decide on which action it can perform can be rather chatty in regards to the options possible.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP requires more network bandwidth and ressources.
One of the most important reasons is the higher overhead (SOAP: XML serialization)

Comment: But even for huge data we use JSon Serialization or other things for Rest. Don't you think it an overhead?

Comment: Answering a statement with the same statement feels a bit wirred IMO. Also, REST responses might get serialized to XML as well, so where is the differenct to SOAP then? Poor quality answer that does attempt not explain anything